# Mocking web server in Component/Functional testing in Python

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to write some component/functional test for my application writed in C++. The application communicates with several http servers. For test I would like to mock these servers to easy handle bad path e.g timeouts. Could you recommend me some python package to do this?

OR

I have tried to use Flask to mock my Http server. My problem with flask is that I don't know how to run it in backgroun non blocking mode.
I have trying:
Using thread and lamba

```
  class MyServerMock:
    def __init__(self, port=5000):
        super().__init__()
        self.port = port
        self.app = Flask(__name__)
        self.url = "http://localhost:{}".format(self.port)

        self.app.add_url_rule("/path/to/function", view_func=self.function, methods=['POST'])

    
    def function(body):
        pass

    def shutdown_server(self):
        self.app.do_teardown_appcontext()

    def run(self):
        self.thread = Thread(target=lambda: self.app.run(port=self.port, debug=False, use_reloader=False)).start()
```

this solution works, but after execution test cases test script is hanging in Flask and I don't know how to proper shutdown Flask.

Thank you from advance for you help.

EDIT 1:
How I use this Flask code:

```
import MyServerMock
import pytest

def test_example():
    mock = MyServerMock(port=6500)
    mock.run()
 
    # testing stuf

    mock.shutdown()
    assert 1 == 2
```

I thinking about doing fixture with this mocking server

Comment: If the real app is not Python, then why introduce Python/Flask as a mock server? [WireMock](https://wiremock.org/) is better suited for this

Comment: How are you using this class in your test? Can you include that code?

Comment: @C_Z_ I edited main post

Comment: @OneCricketeer I would not like to add dependencies to java

Comment: You could use Docker, but you're still "adding dependency" on Flask here. So, if you want no external dependencies, you could run a web server in C++. Also, technically, this is a "fake", not a "mock". You should be able to inject a real mock HTTP response into the API client you use from C++, e.g. "when this path is requested, return that response", "when other path is requested, return a timeout"

Comment: @OneCricketeer I thinking about it but I have to able to modifiy the behaviour of mock server and capture requests from the tested application. So I thing using Flask will be easy, some wrapper to save the request and to do the special case like latency or timeout

Comment: Are you running your C++ tests from Python as well? Otherwise, what is "testing stuf"? Overall, you need some process orchestrator that starts the server, then runs your C++ tests, then stops the server when tests are done. Docker is good at this, or you can use a Makefile, but I don't think it matters what is "blocking" since you can `kill -9` the flask server with a process id, for example.

Comment: @OneCricketeer Generally I want to get something like this: (pseudocode of test)
1) mock server1
2)mock server 2
3) set specific behaviour in server 1, server 2
4)lunch tested application
5)verify behaviour of tested application based on: - request to server 1, request to server 2, tested application logs, make some asserts
6)shutdown application, server1, server2

Answer (score 0):

For a Unix solution, run your test server(s) in the background using `nohup`

```
nohup python server_1.py > server_1.log 2>&1 & 
echo $! > pid_server_1.txt
```

Run some test modules, for example, with a Makefile

```
make test
```

When tests are done, `kill` the server(s) using the saved pid

```
kill $(cat pid_server_1.txt)
```